# Safe test-area in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, virtualization

I have been running Windows 10 in a virtualization for the last couple of years because the work I do has a tendency to eradicate essential files or other important parts of Windows.

It would be much easier if I could make a user account that has full admin access to install programs for itself but that can not mess with the real admin user.

Is that possible or will I have to stick with my virtual machine?

Comment: If your "test area" is only wanted to be temporary, would [Windows Sandbox](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/windows-sandbox/windows-sandbox-overview) suit your needs? It needs Windows 10 Pro, but applications can be run in self-contained and isolated areas similar to a VM (but more lightweight) and everything is discarded when you close the sandbox.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such thing (overall) as a "normal" or "standard" user that can be an administrator and install / remove software.

If your environment is such that things get damaged, I would use a full virtual machine for this work (whatever operating system you wish).

I experimented with Sandbox (have it here on my Insider test machine) and (for me) I do not like the fact that the sandbox is discarded when I close the machine. That is a bit short term for me. However, do consider it, as it may fit you well.

I suggest you create a host operating system (sounds like Windows 10) and then use VMware Workstation or Hyper-V to create Virtual Machines that serve your needs.

The host machine can have two users (Installer and User) and you can work in User normally and switch to Installer to install host software.

The virtual machine can be installer as that appears to be what you need.

With VMware for sure and likely Hyper-V, you can make a backup copy of the working VM and then restore this if something goes wrong with the Guest machine. You can do this for all Guest machines and ensure you can always work.